# Python: allocate certain amount symbol in text file line

Tags: python, text

For example:

```
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   11 Eastern Mediterranean     1980
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    0 Eastern Mediterranean     1981
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    8 Eastern Mediterranean     1982
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI    9 Eastern Mediterranean     1983
```

In this txt file each line contains: 50 symbols for a country name, 6 symbols for GDP, etc. Is there any way to write txt file like this in Python3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can use [text-formatting mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to format the text output. For example:

```
data = [
    ['Afghanistan', 'WB_LI', '11 Eastern Mediterranean', '1980'],
    ['Afghanistan', 'WB_LI', '0 Eastern Mediterranean', '1981'],
    ['Afghanistan', 'WB_LI', '8 Eastern Mediterranean', '1982'],
    ['Afghanistan', 'WB_LI', '9 Eastern Mediterranean', '1983'],
]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for row in data:
        print('{:<50}{:>6}{:>25}{:>6}'.format(*row), file=f_out)
```

Creates file `output.txt` with content:

```
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI 11 Eastern Mediterranean  1980
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI  0 Eastern Mediterranean  1981
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI  8 Eastern Mediterranean  1982
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI  9 Eastern Mediterranean  1983
```